# C Program - Calculate And Display Each Year Population using the provided equation

Tags: c

This is the code I've finished, but for some reasons, which I still can't figure out why. It would display the proper population for year 0 properly, but for year 1, it would take the value of the previous year of population and multiply by the rate instead of using the provided equation that I use in the code
The equation is NextYr = Rate * CurrentYr * (1-(CurrentYr/1000000))

Any help would be much appreciated !

For example,

```
Enter the initial egret population: 12
Enter the rate: 2

Year     Population
  0              12
  1              24
  2              48
  3              96
and so on
```

---

```
#include<stdio.h>
 int main()
{
int count=1,year_num;
float Rate;
unsigned long CurrentYr;
unsigned long NextYr;

while (count<=1)
{
    printf("Enter the initial egret population: ");
    scanf("%d",&CurrentYr);
    printf("Enter the rate: ");
    scanf("%f",&Rate);

    printf("Year  Population\n");
    printf("----  ----------\n");



    if ((CurrentYr>0 && CurrentYr<1000000) && (Rate>0 && Rate<4))
    {
        NextYr = CurrentYr;
        for(year_num=0;year_num<=25;year_num++)
        {
            NextYr = Rate * NextYr * (1-NextYr/1000000);
            printf("%4d%12d\n",year_num,NextYr);

        }
        break;
    }

    else if ((CurrentYr < 0 || CurrentYr > 1000000) || (Rate<0 || Rate>4))
    {
        printf("Invalid Input!");
        printf("Enter the initial egret population: ");
        scanf("%d",&CurrentYr);
        printf("Enter the rate: ");
        scanf("%f",&Rate);
    if ((CurrentYr>0 && CurrentYr<1000000) && (Rate>0 && Rate<4))
    {
        NextYr = CurrentYr;

        for(year_num=0;year_num<=25;year_num++)
        {
            printf("%4d%12d\n",year_num,NextYr);
            NextYr = Rate * NextYr * (1-NextYr/1000000);


        }
        break;

    }
    else
    {
        printf("No more chance ! Bye ! ");
    }
}
return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: NextYr/1000000 is an integer division (yields 0 if NextYr in [0,1000000)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the formula copied from your code:

```
        NextYr = Rate * NextYr * (1-NextYr/1000000);
```

So if `Rate` is 2 and `NextYr` is 12, what do you think this will be:

```
Rate * NextYr * (1-NextYr/1000000);
```

Since `NextYr` is an integer, `NextYr/1000000` will be 0, so we are left with

```
2 * 12 * (1 - 0)
```

and indeed your program prints `24` as the value for year 2. Why do you think that's incorrect output?

Maybe you should try with larger numbers of egrets (closer to a million).
Also, you probably don't want to do `NextYr/1000000` with integer arithmetic, which will always round down to 0 as long as `NextYr` is less than a million.
Try something like `NextYr/1000000.0`; by making one of the values floating-point you will cause the division to be floating-point. I'd probably write `((float)NextYr)/1000000.0` just to be extra clear what we want, though.

You might also try a rate closer to 1.

Comment: Thank you so much
This is what I change my code to

`NextYr = Rate * NextYr * (1-(((float)NextYr)/1000000.0));`